# How to update parent controller variables in child controller

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In parent controller, like this:

```dart
@NgController(
  selector: '[main-ctrl]',
  publishAs: 'ctrl')
class MainController {
  Scope scope;
  bool showHeaderFooter=false;
}
```

In child controller, how to update showHeaderFooter variable?

```dart
@NgController(
selector: '[login-ctrl]',
publishAs: 'login')
class LoginController {
  Scope scope;
  NgRoutingHelper routingHelper;
  var username, pwd;

  LoginController(this.routingHelper,this.scope);

  void login(){
    if(username!=null&&pwd!=null){
      routingHelper.router.go('welcome', {});
      scope.parentScope.showHeaderFooter=true;
    }
  }
}
```

this code can not working.

Comment: Do you mind modifying the parent controller to make this possibly or should the parent controller be ignorant of this?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer
In AngularJs, we can used emit and on event to change parent scope variables, but I am not clear how to implement this in angular-dart.

Comment: I try to make a simple example using `emit`. Can you take a look at my current answer and maybe add some information about your preferred approach.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your code is ok, but I don't understand "(scope.parentScope.context['mainCtrl'] as MainController).showHeaderFooter=true;" and "scope.context['mainCtrl'] = this;"

can you provided more information or documentation for this?

Comment: I added some explanation at the top of my answer but I think using `emit` is the better approach. `parentScope` only works if you know that `MainController` is actually your direct parent scope. `emit` works for all ancestors.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, the emit and on method also works, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities.

- Access the parent using `scope.context`

  1. In `MainController` you assign the instance of `MainController` to a named attribute in its scope when it is created (in its constructor)
  2. You get access to the parent scope using from `LoginController` by `scope.parentScope` and then the attribute where the instance is assigned to.
- Events using emit, assigning the `MainCntroller` to a scope attribute, then you can access it with

```dart
@NgController(
  selector: '[main-ctrl]',
  publishAs: 'ctrl')
class MainController {
  Scope scope;
  bool showHeaderFooter=false;
  MainController(this.scope) {

    // approach using emit
    scope.on('login').listen((e) => showHeaderFooter = e.data);

    // approach using scope.context
    scope.context['mainCtrl'] = this;

    // just for demonstration
    new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (e) => print(showHeaderFooter));
  }

}

@NgController(
selector: '[login-ctrl]',
publishAs: 'login')
class LoginController {
  Scope scope;
  NgRoutingHelper routingHelper;
  var username, pwd;

  LoginController(this.routingHelper,this.scope);

  void login(){
//    if(username!=null&&pwd!=null){
      //routingHelper.router.go('welcome', {});

      // approach using emit
      scope.emit('login', true);

      // approach using scope.context
      (scope.parentScope.context['mainCtrl'] as MainController).showHeaderFooter=true;
//    }
  }
}
```

or if you `MainController` has an unique `publishAs` and a `@NgTwoWay('showHeaderFooter')` annotation you can just create a binding.